# Topographic correction (for land use classification) with SAGA or GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, saga

Is there a module in GRASS or SAGA (or a alternative open program) to do a topographic correction of a landsat image to enhance the land use classification?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the GRASS addon: i.topo.corr: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_AddOns#i.topo.corr.  There's a wiki page devoted to atmospheric correction:  http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Atmospheric_correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SAGA:

```
Module Name
Topographic Correction
Menu Terrain Analysis > Lighting
```

Note that you can always search for a module by right clicking "module library"in the workspace tab.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a direct answer, but I can't make comments. I haven't used any of the tools on the page but have you had a look at the [GRASS image processing page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/imageryintro.html)? It lists GRASS tools for classification and image correction.

Answer (score 1):

In GRASS, use i.topo.corr. See http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_processing#Correction_for_topographic.2Fterrain_effects